# show/hide Form element using radio button

Tags: javascript, forms

Here is my code. If I click on `From`'s radio button, it will display 2 more options. If I click on `To`'s radio button, it will display 2 more options. But if I click on `Full Day`'s radio button, options `From` and `To` should disappear.

When I click on `Full Day`, only one option disappears. I want both to disappear. How can I do this?

```js
function show1() {
  document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'none';
}

function show2() {
  document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'block';
}

function show3() {
  document.getElementById('div2').style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: arial;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

p {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<p>Leave</p>
<input type="radio" name="tab" value="igotnone" onclick="show1();" /> Full Day
<input type="radio" name="tab1" value="igottwo" onclick="show2();" /> From
<input type="radio" name="tab2" value="igottwo" onclick="show3();" /> To

<div id="div1" class="hide">
  <hr>
  <p>From Which Half Session You Are Not Available???</p>
  <input type="radio" value="Yes" name="one"> First Session&nbsp;
  <input type="radio" value="Yes" name="one"> Second Session
</div>

<div id="div2" class="hide">
  <hr>
  <p>To Which Half Session You Are Not Available???</p>
  <input type="radio" value="Yes" name="two"> First Session&nbsp;
  <input type="radio" value="Yes" name="two"> Second Session
</div>
```

Comment: Your 'session' radio inputs all have the same `value`, so you'll not know which one was selected. It also makes more sense to show the same set of Session options as they are identical. Repeating them is pointless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly the name of all the radio button should be same. So, it can select one at a time.
second the div you are displaying at the same time hide the other div.

```js
function show1() {
  document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('div2').style.display = 'none';
}

function show2() {
document.getElementById('div2').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'block';
}

function show3() {
document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('div2').style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: arial;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

p {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<p>Leave</p>
<input type="radio" name="tab" value="igotnone" onclick="show1();" /> Full Day
<input type="radio" name="tab" value="igottwo" onclick="show2();" /> From
<input type="radio" name="tab" value="igottwo" onclick="show3();" /> To

<div id="div1" class="hide">
  <hr>
  <p>From Which Half Session You Are Not Available???</p>
  <input type="radio" value="Yes" name="one"> First Session&nbsp;
  <input type="radio" value="Yes" name="one"> Second Session
</div>

<div id="div2" class="hide">
  <hr>
  <p>To Which Half Session You Are Not Available???</p>
  <input type="radio" value="Yes" name="two"> First Session&nbsp;
  <input type="radio" value="Yes" name="two"> Second Session
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may wrap the two `div`s into one `div` and show/hide that only.

Moreover, radio buttons should share the same `name` to allow users to choose only one option at a time.

```js
function show1() {
  document.getElementById('divs').style.display = 'none';
}

function show2() {
  document.getElementById('divs').style.display = 'block';
}

function show3() {
  document.getElementById('divs').style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: arial;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

p {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<p>Leave</p>
<input type="radio" name="tab" value="igotnone" onclick="show1();" /> Full Day
<input type="radio" name="tab" value="igottwo" onclick="show2();" /> From
<input type="radio" name="tab" value="igottwo" onclick="show3();" /> To

<div id="divs" class="hide">
  <div id="div1">
    <hr>
    <p>From Which Half Session You Are Not Available???</p>
    <input type="radio" value="Yes" name="one"> First Session&nbsp;
    <input type="radio" value="Yes" name="one"> Second Session
  </div>

  <div id="div2">
    <hr>
    <p>To Which Half Session You Are Not Available???</p>
    <input type="radio" value="Yes" name="two"> First Session&nbsp;
    <input type="radio" value="Yes" name="two"> Second Session
  </div>
</div>
```